# Flash go to frame label action

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

It is my first time using AS3.

The way that is set up us I have a "Main MOvie Clip" and inside the main movie clip I have another movie clip which is the MainMenu.

Inside the MainMenu are buttons. The frame label I wanted to go to in outside of the MainMenu but Inside of the MainMovieClip.

I am doing a small project that involves `gotoAndPlay("frame label")`

**In the action layer at the end of the timeline of the MainMenu Moviclip Here is my code:**

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay("nordic");
}

stop();
```

**The error I get:**

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access
>   a property or method of a null object
>   reference.    at
>   Ronor_CD20100421_fla::mainMenu_3/frame27()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code resides in MainMenu and MainMenu is located in the MainMovieClip you should use:

```
function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay("yourLabel");
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the object you want to change. For example:

```
mainMovieClip.gotoAndPlay("nordic");
```